# Grails Mongodb plugin does not save

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I have a requirement in my grails app to connect to an existing mongodb server.  I am using the plugin ':mongodb:3.0.3' to do this.  I have a domain class that is basically empty

```
 class Thing {
    static mapWith = "mongo"

    String id
    String name

    static constraints = { }

    static mapping = {
        collection "myThing"
        id column: '_id', generator: 'assigned'
        version false
    }
}
```

And I am trying to save a new domain object in an integration test -- a precursor to a controller action:

```
def "create the thing"() {
    def thing = new Thing(name: "name", id:"foobar")

    when:
    def foo = thing.save(flush: true, failOnError:true)

    then:
    Thing.findByName("name")
}
```

The test fails because Thing.findByName returns null, however, when I dig into the low level API, I can save an object.  The following test passes:

```
def "create the thing low level"() {
    when:
    Thing.collection.insert([name:"name"])

    then:
    Thing.findByName("name")
}
```

I have looked at the other stackoverflow questions and they seem to deal with:

- Not using flush, which I am
- Not having the configuration setup propertly, which I do because I have been fetching records from it, and the low level API works.
- constraint errors which I don't have since failOnError is true

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get GORM saves to work because I would like to use the grails tools available.

**NOTE**: This is not just a test issue, trying to save something in a controller using GORM also does not work.  Calling this action:

```
def save() {
    def thing = new Thing()
    thing.name = "foobar"
    respond thing.save(failOnError: true, flush: true)
}
```

Returns `{ "class": "com.Thing", "id": null, "name": "foobar" }` and a look at the database tells me it is not saved.

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line at the top of your integration test and it should start saving. By default GORM will not persists even in IntegrationTests

```
static Boolean transactional = false
```

You test would look something like below,

```
class TestIntegrationSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
   static Boolean transactional = false

   def "my test"() {
     ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: I added that line to the top of the file and it still fails in the same way. Since I am not using a transactional service, and did not create a transaction myself, I am not sure how transactions enter into the equation.  From what I understand, integration tests have transactions, they just roll back at the end by default.

Comment: @adeady Hmmm... if I add this line in POSTGRES it works and persists in db. There could be some difference when it comes to Mongo I guess.

Comment: yeah, postgres would have no problem with it.  I do suspect it is a plugin or database issue -- but the internet does not seem to have anyone else with this problem that I can find